# __init__ function definition without self argument

Tags: python

In digging through the python `Counter` class in `collections`, I found something I thought was peculiar: They don't explicitly use the `self` argument in the `__init__` function's arguments.

See code below (copied directly without the docstring):

```
class Counter(dict):
    def __init__(*args, **kwds):
        if not args:
            raise TypeError("descriptor '__init__' of 'Counter' object "
                            "needs an argument")
        self, *args = args
        if len(args) > 1:
            raise TypeError('expected at most 1 argments, got %d' % len(args))
        super(Counter, self).__init__()
        self.update(*args, **kwds)
```

Later in this same class, the `update` and `subtract` methods are also defined this same way.

Before you point me to questions about how `self` works in classes, I will note that I don't believe this is a duplicate question. I understand how `self` works typically and that `self` is not a keyword (just standard practice) etc. I also understand that this code works (I'm not questioning the validity of the `*` unpack/explode/starred-expressions syntax)

My question is more related to why...

- Why would one implement the `__init__` and other normal (non-`@static`/`@class` methods) of a class like this and in what circumstances should I consider using this in the future?
- Why are only specific methods on the same class implemented like this?
- Under what circumstance would these methods be called without any args (if any), triggering the first TypeError?
- In what circumstances would these methods be called with `self` filled in manually (e.g. `Counter.__init__(some_counter)`)? Or other examples?

I have to think that it has something to do with the TypeError("descriptor...").

---

### Edit 11/2020:

In Python 3.8, [PEP570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) introduces Positional-Only Parameters, eliminating the need to use `(*args, **kwds)` in this way. This can be seen in the [Python 3.8 Counter code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L540):

```py
def __init__(self, iterable=None, /, **kwds):
```

Comment: It does use self: `self, *args = args`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This code is intended to make `self` positional-only. Otherwise, a call like

```
d = {'self': 5}
Counter(**d)
```

would fail due to `__init__` receiving two values of `self`.

Most classes don't need anything like this special handling, but `Counter` is supposed to handle keyword arguments like `dict` does, where they become keys of the resulting mapping, even if the key is `'self'`. The other `Counter` methods that have this handling are the ones that need the same keyword argument behavior.

If you need to treat `self` as a valid keyword argument in your own code, you should probably do something similar.

---

As for the `TypeError`, that's there to match the error message from `dict.__init__`:

```
>>> dict.__init__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'dict' object needs an argument
>>> Counter.__init__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 560, in __init__
    raise TypeError("descriptor '__init__' of 'Counter' object "
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'Counter' object needs an argument
```

The most likely way for this to come up in practice is probably people subclassing `Counter` and forgetting to pass `self` to `Counter.__init__` (or use `super`).

Comment: I like this! Very clever stuff.

Any sort of short explanation about the `TypeError` itself? I understand enough why it's there, but what does it mean: "descriptor"?

Comment: @StephenCowley: The [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) is the protocol that methods use to automatically bind the `self` argument when accessed on an instance. It's useful for more than that, but that's what methods use it for. The descriptor types used for most C methods say "descriptor 'method_name' of 'type_name' needs an argument" if called without the `self` positional argument.